# How can i remove a singleton spring bean from ApplicationContext?

Tags: spring, lifecycle

I want to develop a **module control system** so that every spring bean can be managed by my own LifeCycle Controller.

But I can not figure out how can I remove a singleton spring bean out of ApplicationContext.

That may be an interesting problem , can you help me to resolve ?

Comment: This is a highly peculiar thing to do.  What are you trying to achieve? if you give us a higher-level description, maybe we can suggest a more conventional alternative.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can try removing the bean definition. Get the [`BeanDefinitionRegistry`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistry.html#removeBeanDefinition%28java.lang.String%29) and call `removeDefinition(..)`

It depends on the way you create your application, but for example in web application you can get the definition registry by:

```
BeanDefinitionRegistry factory = 
   (BeanDefinitionRegistry) applicationCtx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
```

(the bean factory implements `BeanDefinitionRegistry`).

I don't know if the bean instance will be removed as well. Give it a try.

Comment: just implements BeanFactoryAware and then cast BeanFactory with DefaultListableBeanFactory

Answer (score 56):

Removing definition does both : removing definition and destroying (removing all container references on that bean) corresponding Singleton :

```
((BeanDefinitionRegistry) beanFactory).removeBeanDefinition("myBean");
```

If you just need to remove the singleton then :

```
((DefaultListableBeanFactory) beanFactory).destroySingleton("myBean");
```

The latter way may be especially useful if you just registered singleton but haven't defined any bean definitions,  i.e.

```
((SingletonBeanRegistry) beanFactory).registerSingleton("myBean", myBeanInstance);
```