# Make a bean unautowireable or that disposes of it self?

Tags: spring

We need a spring bean that will either

Prevent the framework from @Autowired -ing it.

or

Once it does its work it destroys itself?

The bean roughly looks like this:

```
public final class Registrar implements ApplicationListener<SOFrameworkInitializedEvent>
```

So after it receives this 1 time event do the work and go away.  We are using Spring 3.0.7.

Comment: Go away? Is your concern memory? Or that you don't want rogue client code calling it?

Comment: Rogues, they are everywhere

Comment: Then see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855811/how-can-i-remove-a-singleton-spring-bean-from-applicationcontext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `autowire-candidate` property in the bean definition XML, e.g.:

```
  <bean id="MyBean" class="com.acme.SimpleTestServiceImpl" autowire-candidate="false"/>
```