# How delete spring managed beans from application context?

Tags: java, spring

I have some code that runs in a `ServletContextListener` and several beans are created/autowired using the root application context.

Most of these beans are only needed for this routine although some are redefined in the dispatcher servlet application context. Since these beans in the root application context are only used for the duration of this routine, is it possible for them to be deleted when the routine completes?

Comment: You can try set the bean instance to null in the application context, but it really depends how Spring would react to having something set to null under its feet.  It's worth a try anyway imho.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i remove a singleton spring bean from ApplicationContext?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855811/how-can-i-remove-a-singleton-spring-bean-from-applicationcontext)