# How can we remove/ignore an object before refresh AnnotationconfigwebapplicationContext in spring?

Tags: java, spring

I have 2 dependent applications. When my child application up we update some more beans and refresh the `AnnotationconfigwebapplicationContext` object, but after refresh the context my `MqttConnection` object gets started being connected and disconnect.
I don't want to refresh my `Mqttconnection` object.

Please suggest how I can ignore/remove the `MqttConnection` object from `AnnotationconfigwebapplicationContext` before the refresh.

```java
    static{
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    context.regirster(MqttConnection.class);
    context.register(Config.class);
    
    if(checkChildServiceup()){
      Class<?>[] configClasses = getServletConfigClasses();
      if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(configClasses)) {
        this.context.register(configClasses);
      }
      this.context.refresh();
     }
     
     }
      
     
    public static Class<?> getServletConfigClasses(){
    retrun new Class[]{AppConfig.class,devService.class,DbConfiguration.class}; 
    }
    
    public boolean static checkChildServiceup(){
      while(true){
          
    if(up){
    return true;
    break;    
      }
    }
```

Comment: For the next time, please check the code you paste is okay-ish. Your `returns` are written as `retrun` and you have a `break;` after a `return true;`, which makes it unreachable code and does not compile.

Answer (score 0):

During the refresh, the following happens in spring:

1. It scans all the "resources" of configurations (XMLs, java @Config files, classes annotated with @Component and its derivatives and so forth) And creates Bean Definitions which is a metadata for each bean. Note, bean definition is a meta object, its not the bean object itself.
2. Calls hooks called "BeanFactoryPostProcessor"-s. These allow to alter the bean definition registry - an object that aggregates all the "information" resolved during step
3. Initializes beans: creates, autowires, etc.

So you might be required to implement your own BeanFactoryPostProcessor that will check the property set dynamically as I see and will remove the bean definition of `MqttConnection` from the registry.

```
@Component // (or register in @Configuration annotated class):
// this must be a spring driven bean by itself, 
// it resolves it but "puts aside" because it 
// recognizes that its a special "hook" 

public class SampleBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanFactory (
            ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory)
            throws BeansException {

       if(<WHATEVER_PROPERTY_CHANGED__PERFORM_THE CHECK)) {
         ((BeanDefinitionRegistry) beanFactory).removeBeanDefinition("myBean");
      }
  }
}
```

As for actual removal of the bean definition there are many possible options here, make sure you read [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855811/how-can-i-remove-a-singleton-spring-bean-from-applicationcontext) and also [this tutorial](https://www.javaprogramto.com/2019/07/spring-dynamically-register-beans.html) for examples.

Comment: Thanks but some of the objects which are refreshing are using @Autowired Mqtt Connection they are not using old reference hence they are failing.

Comment: So what would you like to do with this components? You could alter the bean definition to create a no op. Proxy for Mqtt connection or something? Its also possible to use bean post processor for that...

Comment: I saw that you've accepted the answer but then removed that... Have you faced any difficulties with this approach? If you find an alternative solution - consider sharing it for the benefit of community.